# Is it possible to change the processor in my camera?

Tags: nikon

I have a **Nikon d300s** and instead of buying a new camera, would changing the **digital processor** even be feasible? I haven't seen it done before and wonder why? It seems like a possibility given that the architecture is *similar to* that of the D500. Could this be a cheaper alternative to buying a new/used camera completely?

Comment: *given that the architecture is similar to that of the D500*  This is not the case.  They are based on completely different custom (electronics) components.

Comment: Just for fun, get hold of a junk camera some day, and disassemble it. Then, try to imagine somebody putting those pieces back together to make it work again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A camera is not a PC where you can swap standard components.

- Physically, the processor's tiny little contacts are soldered on a printed circuit, so you can't change just the processor, you would have to change the electronics, and it's unlikely that a circuit from a new camera fits in the old (size, but also fixation points). These new electronics would also have to handle the old sensor (not too likely).
- Logically, you would have to find/write a firmware for your new processor that works on the output of the old sensor, and works with the rest of the camera: focus points, controls, display. Also rather unlikely.

So you are more or less redesigning a new camera.

Comment: Ah I see. The second bullet point, I was thinking about when I wrote the question out. Seems like it would take too much effort to do this!

Comment: Just replacing the existing sensor with another D300s sensor (the correct part number) would cost far more than the camera is worth, and an appreciable amount of the cost of a new D500. It's very labor intensive and only really makes sense for higher end cameras that are still fairly new..